# Raspberry not booting correctly (mmc0: fsm1, hsts 1)

Tags: boot

I have a problem when booting my Raspberry. It shows me this:

[image: The error is: mmc0: fsm1, hsts 1]

I have no idea why is this happening, so I don't know what information you people are going to need to help me, so let me know and I'll answer as soon as I can.

Comment: 1: has it ever worked? 2: what was the last thing you did before it broke? 3: Can you rebuild from scratch?

Comment: @rob It was working. I did nothing special, I was using motion to use a camera and apart of that a relay. I could, but I prefer not to, but if that's the only option...

Comment: It looks like your sd card is about to go belly up. My advise is to get a new card, and rebuild. Then you may use an sd card reader to mount the old sd card and copy your code/project to the new card. My card broke too, when i was using motion to capture video snippets of sheep at a drinking bowl. Perhaps you should review how often you write to the card?

Comment: @jogco is right... I just copy my project to a new sd card and it worked again... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied my project to a new sd card and it worked again.

Thanks @jogco for the solution.